# How to Implement Inertial / Momentum Scrolling in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, scroll, momentum

I am trying to implement inertial / momentum scrolling in my react app.
The intended behaviour is that when the "up or down arrow key" is pressed, it begins scrolling, the scrolling velocity would keep increasing as the key remains pressed, and when the key is released, the scroll velocity should dissipate gradually, which package can i use to achieve this?